# Displaying Hi5, Orkut, LinkedIn, and Twitter etc. Pages in Power.com website

Tags: frames

I am wondering how Power.com is able to display Hi5, Orkut, LinkedIn, and Twitter etc. links in their website pages. As far I know Twitter breaks Iframes as they use some JavaScript(Frame breaker scipt) to break frames.

Would you please let me know if you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't twitter etc have their own API's that you can hook into to expose the data?

e.g.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/

**EDIT**
An API will allow you to connect to a service (Web service, REST service) to grab the data in say an XML/JSON format. You will then be able to transform this data via XSLT etc on your web page.